# Telerik ASP.NET MVC dropdownlist multiselect supporting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I use Telerik ASP.NET MVC component. I need to implement multiselect functionality on dropdownlist but Telerik dropdownlist component doesnt support multiselect.

Is there any way or how to implement multiselect functionality on that component?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're searching for a listbox(see a demo [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/listbox/examples/clientside/clientevents/defaultcs.aspx)).
Telerik did not implement this feature in their mvc library, you're stuck with using something other then telerik or switching to webforms(i'd recommend the first option ;) ).

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, but i dont change form structure or dont add new dll files (telerik asp.net ajax component etc.) so  i must solve on telerik asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 0):

I have had much success using the Telerik Kendo Grid as a Multi-Select List Box.  It does take a bit of tweaking though.  The easiest way is to capture the Select event and dynamically create a CSV list of the selected values and store them in a hidden form field.  You can then pass this around pretty easy.  And it looks cool too.  Hope this helps, or gives you some other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems that even [Kendo UI ComboBox](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/combobox/index.html) (MVC wrapper) does not provide such an option like the [Rad ComboBox](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/checkboxes/defaultcs.aspx) does.

Theoretically, you can try to simulate this UI via the [templates](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/combobox/template.html).

I believe it is better to contact their support for clarification.